# ASP NET error when having 2 concurrent user access the same method / function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, concurrency

I got problem while implementing ASP NET. Here is my code

> ```
>    Dim submitThread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf submit_thread)
>    submitThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
>    submitThread.Start()
> ```
>
> inside submit_thread function there are long looping method in local variables. When only 1 user hit the button, it works well and that method completed is less then 1 second. But the problem occur when 2 users hit / execute the method at the same time. 1 user will succeed and the other with have error shown on their browser. the second user will have to refresh the page.

NB: I have tried not using thread before, and it result the same error.

How can I solved this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Consider to use syncLock (or similar means) to prevent simulaniously access to the same object/variable from two different threads.

```
'Sample:


Private syncHelperObj As New Object 

Sub LongLoop()

        SyncLock syncHelperObj
            ' accessing global objects/vars here
            '....
        End SyncLock

End Sub
```